# find max for varchar

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hi, I'm working on a java project where I have to retrieve the last customer added id i.e `Max(c_id)`. But in my database `c_id` is in text `(varchar)` format, so how do I retrieve the max?

```
    Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:rrr");
    st=conn.createStatement();

 String query[] ={"SELECT Max(cid) FROM client"};
  for(String q : query){
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);        
     while (rs.next()) {
        String name = rs.getString("cid");
        Text1.setText(name);
```

Comment: Which database (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, etc.)?

Comment: I think your c_id number but in varchar?

Comment: Are you sure that last == max id ?

Comment: im using MS Access,cid is number but in varchar,last== max id..

Comment: Why do you want the last ID? I can't think of many uses for it. (Ones that don't cause problems with more than one user at least.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the following:

select * from client order by cid desc limit 1,1;

Answer (score 3):

`select max(convert(integer, c_id))` or `select max(cast(c_id as integer))` should work

Comment: @Fahim mysql seems to have a slightly different syntax, a quick search came up with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html which may be useful

Comment: where will above code work then?? please update your answer where it will work...

Comment: You mean in the link to documentation I gave? I cannot find any `id` there at all.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 select max(c_id::integer) from tbluser ;
```

If you are using postgresql Database

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
SELECT max(convert(c_id, signed)) FROM client
```

try this in mysql,

```
SELECT max(cast(c_id AS signed)) FROM client
```

can you check with cint function to cast on Ms Access

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

select max(convert(cid,DECIMAL)) from client;

Comment: thanks for help . itried with count (*) statement and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following query.

select * from client order by c_id desc limit 1,1;

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT Max(cast(cid as signed)) FROM client
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT Max(to_number(cid)) FROM client
```

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT Max(CONVERT(int, cid)) FROM client
```